# Tree satisfying BST property But I think it is not BST?

Tags: c, algorithm, tree

Today i am doing a problem on Binary Trees during which I found a structure of BSTree which is satisfying property : "Every node has smaller value on its left child and greater value on its right child". But it is not a BST ( in my opinion ) because root has smaller value than one  of its grand child.Please Explain me all this .

Binary tree :

```
      7
     /  \
    4    10
   / \
  2   8
```

Tell me is this BST or Not ? Explain .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more correct definition of a BST can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree):

> - The left **subtree** of a node contains only nodes with keys less than the node's key.
> - The right **subtree** of a node contains only nodes with keys greater than or equal to the node's key.
> - Both the left and right **subtrees** must also be binary search trees.

So, although your tree satisfies the specific case of every node having a smaller value to its left and a larger value to its right, it does not satisfy the more general case involving the left and right subtrees, and is therefore not a BST.

Comment: thanx friend , Now i am clear with the actual concept of BST.

Answer (score 4):

It's not, 8 > 7 but 8 is on left side of 7.

Comment: As you have stated, "every node should have a smaller value to its left", which is not the case here, so it is not a BST

Answer (score 0):

It is not a BST , as an inorder traversal of the tree will not provide a sorted output . The main culprit is the node with value 8 . It is lying in the left subtree of the root node but is greater than the root node which is 4 .